# Rails way to set up relationship for this model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Being new at Ruby and Rails, I wasn't sure how to explain this in my title so i will do it here. My goal is to create many Products and with those have only one overall Location per submit.

I have a `Product` MVC and a quick ugly sketch of the form would be something like this:

**Overall Location**

```
form_for @product

<p>
<%= f.label :location %>:<br>
<%= f.text_field :location %>
</p>
```

**Product one**

```
<p>
<%= f.label :name %>:<br>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.label :price %>:<br>
<%= f.text_field :price %>
</p>
```

**Product Two** (same)

```
<p>
<%= f.label :name %>:<br>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.label :price %>:<br>
<%= f.text_field :price %>
</p>
```

**Product Three**(same)

```
<p>
<%= f.label :name %>:<br>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
<%= f.label :price %>:<br>
<%= f.text_field :price %>
</p>

<%= f.submit %> 
<% end %>
```

How would you set it up so this relationship could take place so when a user creates 3 products on a form, he has only one location for all 3 of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way:

```
class Location < AR::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Product < AR::Base
  belongs_to :location
end
```

You'd then set up a nested resource route:

```
resources :locations do
  resources :products
end
```

And when you're adding a location, you can add products to it with fields_for.

Comment: The form would be form_for @location instead? Or can i just keep it @product and have the said model and routes?

Comment: form_for @location, fields_for :products

Comment: Thank you, this was a great way to set up for the future.

Answer (score 0):

is it required to use nested_attributes_for in this scenario..

Comment: It doesn't matter, whats the best way you believe in to accomplish having my Products have one location?